# Entity Framework Fluent API - set delete rule to NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2, ef-fluent-api

I have a class called BusinessPortalUser that inherits from IdentityUser (the AspNet Identity Framework implementation).

```
namespace BusinessPortal.Model.Security
{
    public class BusinessPortalUser : IdentityUser
    {
        //code removed
    }
}
```

I then have a class called UserProfile which has a virtual property of BusinessPortalUser with a 1:1 relationship:

```
namespace BusinessPortal.Model.User
{
    public class UserProfile : IModificationHistory
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(80)]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public string AspNetUserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AspNetUserId")]
        public virtual BusinessPortalUser UserCore { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Currently if I try to delete the user via a call to the Identity frameworks DeleteAsync() it errors because there is a row in the User table with a foreign key reference.  What I want to do is delete the core IdentityUser row but set the AspNetUserId string column in the UserProfile table to null/empty varchar, I would then set the Active flag to false but thats not my issue here.

The only way I have been able to achieve what I want to far is:

```
protected override void Seed(BusinessPortal.Core.Repository.BusinessPortalDbContext context)
{
      context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] DROP CONSTRAINT[FK_dbo.User_dbo.AspNetUsers_AspNetUserId]");
      context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.User_dbo.AspNetUsers_AspNetUserId] FOREIGN KEY (AspNetUsersId) REFERENCES dbo.AspNetUsers (Id) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION ON DELETE  SET NULL");
{
```

But I would have thought there was a way of doing it within the fluent API?